Getting transformed coordinates of transformed freehand line in Konva JS
I am using react and Konva and I am storing each coordinate in an array. When I draw a freehand line in Konva JS , I store each coordinate of the line. Now when I transform the freehand drawn line, it gets transformed but I dont know how to get new updated coordinates of the line.
I tried the following code, but It didnt work
    setLines((lines) =>
      lines.map((line) => {
        if (line.id === id) {
          const newPoints = line.points.map(([x, y]) => [
            (x - node.x()) * scaleX + updatedX,
            (y - node.y()) * scaleY + updatedY,
          ]);
          return { ...line, points: newPoints };
        }
        return line;
      })
      
    );

